# multiple assignment in rescue clause?

Tags: ruby, exception, variable-assignment

I ran into this sample code as an idiom for exception handling in Ruby:

```
begin
  eval string
rescue SyntaxError, NameError => boom
  print "String doesn't compile: " + boom
rescue StandardError => bang
  print "Error running script: " + bang
end
```

I'm confused particularly about the local variable assignment line with multiple exceptions:
`rescue SyntaxError, NameError => boom`. Does that mean the local var `boom` will take on either the `SyntaxError` or `NameError` object?  Or is it just the `NameError` that will be assigned?

It's further confusing because the code itself throws a `TypeError`, I think perhaps because `string` is undefined, but that may be beside the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the code above at http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html. Was that your source?

In any event, the local variable in that code is assigned whichever error is raised; it's just specified after the last one.

And yes, it's throwing `TypeError` because the errors do not implicitly coerce to a string in today's Ruby. Perhaps they used to when the book was initially published. You need to add `.message` to the local variable reference to get the error message (e.g. `+ boom.message`).

Comment: Yep, that was my source, but from the physical book. The version available as an e-book hasn't been updated for Ruby 2.0 (I think). Thanks for clearing that up for me, Peter!